Comparing code coverage against previous value
I have an Azure pipeline building the code, running the tests and performing the code coverage calculation propertly.
I'd like to compare the current code coverage in every push in order to fail when the value decreases.
I have tried to save it by using an artifact and cache, but it didn't work.
This is the last part of the yml file to compare, but the file is not found:
- script: 'tools\reportgenerator -reports:$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/coverage.cobertura.xml -targetdir:$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/CodeCoverageReport -reporttypes:HtmlInline_AzurePipelines;Cobertura'
displayName: 'Generate coverage report'

- powershell: |
# Extract the coverage percentage from the Cobertura report
$coverage = (Select-String -Path "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/CodeCoverageReport/Cobertura.xml" -Pattern 'line-rate="(\d+\.\d+)"').Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
$coverage = [math]::Round([double]$coverage * 100, 2)
Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable
Write-Output "Current coverage: $coverage%"

# Save the current coverage to a JSON file
$coverageData = @{ coverage = $coverage }
$coverageData | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage.json"
displayName: 'Extract and save coverage percentage'

- task: CacheBeta@1
inputs:
  key: 'coverage'
  path: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage.json'
displayName: 'Cache coverage file'

- powershell: |
$coverageFilePath = "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage.json"
$currentCoverage = (Get-Content $coverageFilePath | ConvertFrom-Json).coverage
if (Test-Path $coverageFilePath) {
  $previousCoverage = Get-Content $coverageFilePath | ConvertFrom-Json
  $previousCoverage = [math]::Round([double]$previousCoverage.coverage, 2)
  Write-Output "Previous coverage: $previousCoverage%"
  if ($currentCoverage -lt $previousCoverage) {
    Write-Error "Coverage has decreased from $previousCoverage% to $currentCoverage%"
    exit 1
  }
} else {
  Write-Output "No previous coverage file found. Skipping comparison."
}

# Save the current coverage for future comparisons
$coverageData = @{ coverage = $currentCoverage }
$coverageData | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/coverage.json"
displayName: 'Compare coverage and fail if decreased'`enter code here`

My first though was save the percent to cache and use it to compare the current code coverage but I have a cache miss when I save it in "Cache coverage file".
Maybe, I should try another strategy for my goal.

$currentCoverage where defined ?

In a previous powershell script

I do not think you can pass $currentCoverage variable Straightforwardly, you should use task.setvariable then used it in next task. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash

You are right. I added more code above.
